# Mac OS X - Shell script to trap system put to sleep and locked events

Tags: bash, macos, callback

I want to capture event that computer is put to sleep (or) computer is locked through shell script. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The sleep one is certainly possible, but you may not have much time to execute code before the system sleeps. What are you trying to do at sleep time?

Comment: It will be ok even if i get awake notification and time at which system was put to sleep. How can we do that?

Comment: I don't have an easy example, but if you open an [issue against WakeWatcher](https://github.com/erluko/WakeWatcher/issues) asking for the feature, I'll add it for you. I'd previously [removed that feature](https://github.com/erluko/WakeWatcher/commit/d5e01b1b646b0b3c50762978b48e5f416298b6e9/WakeWatcher/WakeWatcher.m).

Comment: https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-02-01-how-to-run-an-applescript-on-wake-up/